# Computing convex hull of table using PostGIS Query in MapServer?

Tags: postgis, convex-hull

I am basically trying to compute the convex hull of a table in postgresql but I can't seem to get the query correct. My ultimate goal is to use this query as a polygon layer. The columns in the table i am trying to query contains: 
the_geom, name, gid.

Here is my map file declarations:

```
 LAYER 
 NAME         res
 DATA         res
 STATUS       ON
 TYPE         POLYGON
 DUMP    TRUE
 CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
 CONNECTION "user=blue password=applesnoranges dbname=dappl host=127.0.0.1"
 DATA "the_geom from (SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom))
    FROM resturants) as blankers using unique gid using SRID=5570"
 CLASS
   NAME       "Resturants"
   STYLE
     COLOR        232 232 232
     OUTLINECOLOR 32 32 32
   END
 END
```

END

Here is my query statement:

```
    the_geom from (SELECT ST_ConvexHull(ST_Collect(the_geom))
    FROM resturants) as blankers using unique gid using SRID=5570;
```

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: Is that the entire query? I ask because that will just give you a syntax error. What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you try to run the query in postgre first before try it in mapserver ?

Comment: yes I did run it in pg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation page on `ST_ConvexHull`](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_ConvexHull.html) gives a good example. You should just need:

```
SELECT ST_ConvexHull(
    ST_Collect(r.the_geom::geometry)
) AS the_geom
FROM restaurants AS r;
```

To store the result in a table that can't be visualised in (e.g.) QGIS, you need to use this statement as part of the definition of a view, or as part of a `CREATE TABLE` or `INSERT INTO`. Software differs on whether you need to define your own UUID column. There are good answers on StackOverflow about generating these. The simplest way to create a new table with your result is:

```
CREATE TABLE ch AS
SELECT ST_ConvexHull(
    ST_Collect(r.the_geom::geometry)
) AS the_geom
FROM restaurants AS r;
```

You can also predefine a schema and indexes and use `INSERT INTO`.

Comment: thanks for the response. But My problem is adding the query as a layer in a  gis map. Understand?

Comment: OK so this depends a little on what you're using to display layers. Most likely you just need to store this result as a table (or a view). I'll edit this in.

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed the mapfile declaration for MapServer (I think? — I've never used that). I would still be inclined to store this query as a view, and refer to it in that declaration, which is essentially what your're doing already with the query inside that text file, but at the database level.

Comment: Did you test the query that selects the convex hull "as the_geom" in your map file? Your title and tags are a bit misleading if the main problem is how to use subquery in MapServer mapfiles.

Comment: Yes i did test the query. The query is/was unsuccessful.